# Continuous time signal and Discrete time signal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, signal-processing

I know that all periodic continuous time signal have discrete spectral representations, but are all discrete spectral representations periodic in continuous time?

Also, can all periodic signals be represented by a fourier series?

Comment: This is a fine question. I think the reason people are downvoting you is because of the allcaps title. There is also another website u could ask this on instead: dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope! Consider:

$$\cos(t)+\cos(\pi t) $$

It's Fourier transform is certainly discrete, but the signal isn't periodic because $\pi$ is irrational. No integer multiple of periods is going to get you back to where you started.